# Deployment with manual confirmation of each change

Tags: gitlab, cicd

I am new to CI/CD and Gitlab.
I have a Python project for parsing a LaTeX book to HTML and uploading those HTMLs to our online course platform.

Without CI/CD my pipeline would look like this:

1. Fix LaTeX source files of my book
2. Run scripts for creating HTML files (some artifacts from my changes)
3. Running script which compares old and new version of each HTML file and asks for a confirmation to upload those changes to the online platform.

I can handle the first step with the Gitlab version control system. I've learned to build artifacts for step 2 with Gitlab's CI pipeline.

My question is: How can I perform 3rd stage of my pipeline (checking what is updated and confirming what should be uploaded/deployed) with Gitlab CD?

Answer (score 0):

I see two scenarios here:

1. Script compares old and new. You could check that output on the stage, e.g. `stage: compare`. Then you could use `when: manual` to apply the changes when you are fine with it.
2. You could do step 1 for each file separately, so you have a stage for every file like `stage: compare_file1` and so on.

Comment: Hey! I am not sure if this is suitable for me. Second option is off, because I have too many files (100+). First option is not particularly clear, how can I verify my files change? With some interface?